# Is my CPU broken?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I bought new laptop HP with i5 8265U CPU and in daily usage I noticed some lags. I run AIDA stability test for CPU and it works fine (1.6-2.4GHZ) during 30 minutes, but when I run test for CPU + GPU i see very strange behavior after test run: CPU Frequency goes down to 400MHZ with equal interval. Laptop connected to power. CPU Temperature in stress test is always lower than 65 C. Windows power profile - Max performance

Can this be a problem with software or this is hardware problem?
[image]

**UPD:**
HP gave me a refund for a broken laptop (under warranty - thermal indicator on the motherboard was broken)

Comment: That looks like thermal throttling. What are your CPU and GPU temperatures when this is happening (search for GPU-z)? Have you cleared out any vents and fans of dust buildup? Thermal paste might also be an issue.

Comment: @Mokubai This is new laptop it is clean, AIDA shows that temperature is 58 degrees celsius and it is not hot when it happens.

Comment: The laptop might not feel hot, but the CPU thermal junction temp might be too high. Check your BIOS for thermal settings, and make the appropriate tweaks.

Comment: @spikey_richie in BIOS I have only 1 setting for thermal functions - "Fans always on" and it is enabled

Comment: Are you running a stock clock speed, with turbo etc... set to automatic?

Comment: @spikey_richie I don't have turbo boost setting in bios, and CPU always works with enabled turbo boost

Comment: This is a CPU with an on-board/embedded GPU? Or you have a separate GPU device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102800/discussion-between-nueq-and-spikey-richie).